# How to download images from the URL to images folder-Grails

Tags: image, url, grails, download

I want to download the image from the specific url:like

```
 http://www.someexample.com/data/adImages/filename.png
```

I have used the below code but no luck.!

```
def addresss = {
    def address = "http://www.exap.com/data/Images/file.png".toURL()
    new File("${address.tokenize('/')[-1]}.png").withOutputStream { out ->
  new URL(address).withInputStream { from ->  out << from; }
      }
      }
```

Need help.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You should not download anything into web application inner folder, because when you redeploy the application the files inside will be lost.

Instead, you have to create a folder on your hard-drive and make it accessible (permissions) to the application server.

After that follow this answer to save the file [How to create file in current system from within grails controller action and save data fetched from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800083/how-to-create-file-in-current-system-from-within-grails-controller-action-and-sa) . Note, you're dealing with binary file format!

Comment: ohh okay.! or else can i reuse the images persisting in url without downloading it and saving..!

Comment: yes, you can reuse them. You only need to construct a proper <img> link